# Use regex to do validation in g:TextField

Tags: javascript, regex, grails, gsp

I am working on a grails applications and want the ability to do validation on a g:textField. I just want to make sure that numbers are numbers and words are words. I would like to avoid doing it through JS but if that is the only way, then so be it. Here is what I am trying out.

```
<g:textField type="number" pattern="^(?:[-+]?[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?\$" class="form-control" name="hours" value="${hours}"/></div>
```

Any suggestions or directions? Or should I just do it through JS?

Comment: I don't understand "make sure that numbers are numbers and words are words". The regex in your snippet is for numbers only. How do words fit in? They enter numbers *or* words into this one field? What triggers a numeric check versus a word check? More information please.

Comment: If you want to validate using a regex in the server side, there's an constraint for it: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay in response. So to be more specific, there are 5 textFields, 4 that should contain characters and words and 1 that can ONLY contain numbers and decimal points. The example provided here is for the numbers field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the correct regex. The issue that I was having was about the escape characters and the way they were being interoperated.

```
<g:textField type="number" pattern="^[0-9]+\\s*\$|^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+\\s*\$" required="true" class="form-control" name="hours" value="${deliverable.estimatedHours}"/>
```

This will now check the format for an input string and make sure that it only contains numbers.

Comment: Hi can you help me with my regex: (\$\{(.*?)\}$)|(^([0-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|200)$)
Which is not working in gsp tag, but working with normal html tags