# Pattern attribute for <g:textField>

Tags: validation, grails, input, gsp

I'm already matching the patterns in my domain classes's constraints block, but now have been asked to add the `pattern attribute` to the `<input>` fields in the forms.

For some reason I am having lots of troubles doing this. The patters are working when I am checking them in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) or [html5pattern](http://html5pattern.com/Names), but not working in my `<g:textField>`. Here are the patterns i'm using:

- First/Last names: `"[A-Za-z-' .]{3,20}"`
- Street Address: `[a-zA-Z0-9-#.,: ]`
- Email: `[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$` (even after i'm using `type="email"` for this field, it's failing basic checks)
- And a SEARCH field in a different form: `"[^'\x22\x3A\x3C\x3D\x3E\x7B\x7D]+"` ( ' or " or < or > or = or } or  { are not allowed)

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725035/use-regex-to-do-validation-in-gtextfield take a look here

Comment: thianks @vahid, that helped!